# difference between int( (n+1)/2 ) and (n+1)//2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python for a problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/APM i used

```
t = int(input())
while t > 0:
    n= int(input())

    if n%2 == 0:
        print(-1)
    else:
        n = int((n+1)/2)
        print(n,n-1)
    t -= 1
```

this code and rejected,

but for this :

```
t = int(input())

while t > 0:
    n= int(input())

    if n%2 == 0:
        print(-1)
    else:
        n = (n+1)//2
        print(n,n-1)
    t -= 1
```

accepted, my question is why int((n+1)/2) gives different ans then (n+1)//2 at large number n< 10^18?

Comment: Maybe some kind of overflow protection...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though for small `n`, it is true that `int(n*(n-1)/2) == n*(n-1)//2`, that can fail for large `n`. The reason why is that `/` is floating point division, which can result in loss of information, information that `int()` can't recover:

```
>>> n = 10**18 - 1
>>> n*(n-1)
999999999999999997000000000000000002
>>> n*(n-1)//2
499999999999999998500000000000000001
>>> n*(n-1)/2
5e+35
>>> int(n*(n-1)/2)
500000000000000021210318687008980992
```

The loss of information can be seen in `5e+35` vs. `499999999999999998500000000000000001`

Comment: @gaurav It is integer division. Mathematically, it is the same as `int( / )` but is guaranteed to work for all integers, even ones with hundreds of digits. This is because the computation involves only integers, and doesn't compute an intermediate float.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```py
import sys

print(sys.float_info)

i=(10**17+2)/2
j=(10**16+2)/2

print(i,j)
print(type(i), type(j))

i,j=int(i),int(j)

print(i,j)
print(type(i), type(j))
```

Although you're far from reaching `float` limits - you reached limit of digits that float can store - so everything after this limit will just get truncated in the exponential notation - so it will be the same magnitude of values, yet all the excessive numbers from the back will be `0`.

**Conclusion:**

Converting types requires great care to detail - just use `\\` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The double slash in Python performs integer division, whereas the single slash performs regular old division which may yield a float.

I don't see anywhere in the question you linked to that requires you to have an integer answer, but I imagine the author wanted it to be this way to prevent any floating point precision errors preventing the automated test cases from being successful.